# Average with partial data in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, average, rolling-average

I have data as below, which is partial and few rows are missing. I need an average with data considering the previous available value. Do we have any function available for such an average in sql?

Needed average: 220

Available data for 10 days:

```
1st day: 100
4th day: 200
7th day: 300
10th day: 400
```

Putting the same in a table format:

```
Rows    Date        Partial Continuous(needed)
1       01-Aug-18   100     100     
2                           100
3                           100
4       04-Aug-18   200     200     
5                           200
6                           200
7       07-Aug-18   300     300     
8                           300
9                           300
10      10-Aug-18   400     400     
-----------------------------------
Average             250     220
-----------------------------------
```

I am looking at something like select avg(partial*(nextdate-date))/(lastdate-firstdate) from mytable;

Comment: In your table, you seem to have the averages backwards.

Answer (score 0):

Use a user-defined variable to fill in the missing values.

```
SELECT AVG(normal)
FROM (SELECT IFNULL(continuous, @prev) AS normal, @prev := IF(continuous IS NULL, @prev, continuous)
      FROM (SELECT continuous
            FROM yourTable
            ORDER BY id) AS x
      CROSS JOIN (SELECT @prev := NULL) AS y
) as z
```

Answer (score 0):

What about [AVG()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg)?

```
> SELECT AVG(Normal) FROM table WHERE something;
```

Comment: I don't think the `normal` column really exists, he's just showing that he wants the rows with missing values to inherit the value from the previous line.

Comment: ah - I was wondering if maybe if Anu was calculating `Average` some strange way because with the numbers given the Average of `Normal` (and `Continuous`) is 220, not 250.

Comment: @ keithpjolley : fixed the data. maybe it was scrambled while someone edited it.